# Multiple socket io client connections in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, socket.io, socket.io-java-client

I have to implement client functionality using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java. I have socket.io nodejs server 4.x version. I want to establish around 300-700 socket connections using threadpool `ThreadPoolExecutor` in a loop after some fixed  delay. I have tried to implement this, the socket connections to server established but after sometimes got disconnected.Please help me figure the root cause of the issue of disconnections.
I have tired

- Without using threads at all.
- Using `singleThreadPool`
- Using `fixedThreadPool`
- Using `scheduledThreadPool`

  ```
   ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(200);
   ScheduledFuture<?> future;
   future= executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
   for(int i=1;i<=300;i++) {

           IO.Options options = IO.Options.builder()
                   .setPath("/agent-manager/socket.io")
                   .setTransports(new String[]{Polling.NAME,WebSocket.NAME})
                   .setAuth(token)
                   .build();

            socket = IO.socket(URI.create("wss://localhost:3000"), options);
            socket.on("connect_error", new Emitter.Listener() {
               @Override
               public void call(Object... args) {
                   System.out.println(args[0]);
               }
           }).on("connect", new Emitter.Listener() {
               @Override
               public void call(Object... args) {
                   System.out.println(socket.id() +" "+i+" connected");
               }
           }).on("disconnect", new Emitter.Listener() {
               @Override
               public void call(Object... args) {
                   System.out.println(socket.id() +" "+i+" disconnected");
               }
           });
           socket.connect();
           lock.countDown();
       }
       }, 1000, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       lock.await(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       future.cancel(true);
  ```

In all above cases, disconnections appear after few seconds.
Is there some sort of socket object ttl expiration, connection timeout, or server & client are not sending any data in some time, so due to inactivity the disconnections appears? How to keep connections sustained?